# Как сравнить строки массива?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

начал заниматься java совсем недавно, подскажите. Я создал методы для заполнения вывода и сортировки массива. Мне нужно сравнить строки отсортированного и не отсортированного массивов. При сравнении через equals всегда k=1; как и в моем варианте ниже, подскажите где ошибка.

`````
import java.util.*;
public class lab3 {

    static void fill(int [][] a){
Random ran=new Random(); 
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
a[i][j] = ran.nextInt(50)-15;}

static void print(int[][] a){ 
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){ 
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) 
            System.out.printf("%8d",a[i][j]); 
        System.out.println();}}

static void sort(int[][] a) {    
    for( int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            Arrays.sort(a[i]);
}


public static void main (String[]args) {
    int n = 4, k=0;
int [][] first = new int [n][n];
int [][] second = Arrays.copyOf(first,first.length);
        fill(first); 
        System.out.println("Выходная матрица");
        print(first);
        sort(second);
        System.out.println("Новая матрица"); 
        print(second);
     for(int i=0; i<first.length;i++) {
        if (first[i]==second[i]) {
            k=1;
        }
        else {
            k=0;}
            System.out.println("k=" + k);
        }

        }}````
`````

Answer (score 1):

> Как сравнить строки массива?

Поэлементно.

```
int [][] first = new int [n][n];
fill(first); 

int [][] second = new int [n][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    second[i][j] = first[i][j];

sort(second);

boolean allEqual = true;
for (int i = 0; i < n && allEqual; i++) 
  for (int j = 0; j < n && allEqual; j++) 
    if (first[i][j] != second[i][j]) 
      allEqual = false;
System.out.println(allEqual? "All equal" : "Not all equal");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, только теперь не могу разобраться как нормально вывести, так ка при "equal" k=1; а при "not equal" k=0; Мне же нужно проверить только по строкам, и поэтому строчка прописывается 4 раза, когда они "equal"