# Как найти нулевой элемент массива java?

Tags: java, строки

Условие такое: если строки двух массивов совпадают k=1; если нет и в нем есть нулевой элемент k=max; если нет и нет нулевых элементов k=min.Ругается только на строчку else if (b[i]==0)

```
int k = 0;
int A[]=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
    int [] second = new int [b[i].length];
    for(int j=0;j<b[i].length;j++)
        second[j]=b[i][j];

    Arrays.sort(second);
    int min = second[0];
    int max = second[second.length-1];

    if((b[i][k]==b[i][k+1])&&(b[i][k+1] == b[i][k+2]))
        Arrays.fill(b[i],0);
    if(Arrays.equals(b[i],second)) {
        A[i]=1;

    }

    else if (b[i] == 0) {
        A[i]=max;
    }
    else 
        A[i]=min;
    System.out.println("A[" + (i+1) + "] = " + A[i]);
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1107974/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0

Answer (score 2):

Элементами первого уровня массива `b` являются массивы, а Вы пытаетесь сравнить один из них с нулем.